# JSON and Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

How do I tell Jackson to ignore JSON name?

I have the following POJO:

```
class MyPojo {
   private String ABCName;
}
```

When I have something as:

"ABCName" : "foo" , then Jackson doesn't recognize it throws error.

It expects something as:

"abcName" : "foo".

Code:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

    public class TestJackson {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            MyPojo my = new MyPojo();
            my.setABCName("Foo");
            System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(my));

        }

        private static class MyPojo {


            private String ABCName;
            public void setABCName(String ABCName) {
                this.ABCName = ABCName;
            }

            public String getABCName() {
                return ABCName;
            }
        }

    }
```

Output: {"abcname":"Foo"}

Then I tried annotating ABCName with: @JsonProperty("ABCName")

After I annotated and ran the code, this is what I got: {"ABCName":"Foo","abcname":"Foo"}

It resulted in duplicate.

I have a JSON client that will send in as: "ABCName" : "Foo" and I need to process it in Jackson.

Any workarounds for this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try genson http://code.google.com/p/genson/. The following code should produce the result you are expecting.

```
String json = "{\"ABCName\" : \"foo\"}";
MyPojo my = new MyPojo();
my.setABCName("Foo");

Genson genson = new Genson();
System.out.println(genson.serialize(my));
System.out.println(genson.deserialize(json, MyPojo.class).ABCName);

 public static class MyPojo {
     private String ABCName;
     public void setABCName(String ABCName) {
         this.ABCName = ABCName;
     }

     @JsonProperty("ABCName") public String getABCName() {
         return ABCName;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the following worked with Jackson itself:

```
public class MyPojo {
     private String ABCName;
     public void setABCName(String ABCName) {
         this.ABCName = ABCName;
     }

     @JsonProperty("ABCName") 
public String getABCName() {
         return ABCName;
     }
 }
```

Result: {"ABCName":"Foo"}

But when you annotate the field, it resulted in duplicates, meaning that the following didn't work:

```
public class MyPojo {
         @JsonProperty("ABCName") 
         private String ABCName;
         public void setABCName(String ABCName) {
             this.ABCName = ABCName;
         }


    public String getABCName() {
             return ABCName;
         }
     }
```

Result: {"ABCName":"Foo","abcname":"Foo"}

Looks like the annotation got to be above the getter method.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can try jackson itself by setting annotation introspector as follows

public class TestJackson {

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
        MyPojo my = new MyPojo();
        my.setABCName("Foo");
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(my));

    }

    private static class MyPojo {

        @JsonProperty("ABCName")
        private String ABCName;
        public void setABCName(String ABCName) {
            this.ABCName = ABCName;
        }

        public String getABCName() {
            return ABCName;
        }
    }

}
```